# Stuck in writing sql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

i have a table where termid,termversion are two primary key.
column present in table - termid,termversion,name

I want to select all term whose name ilike `'%AB%'` and the result should contain each matching term with maximum version number.

Example:

```
id    name   ver
1     ABBBB  1
1  ABBBB  2
1  ABBBB 3
2  ABC   1
2  ABC   2
```

output should come

```
1 ABBBB 3
2 ABC   2
```

I want to write this query in hibernate using 
Criteria...if any one can suggest me in hibernate then its really good else at least help me in writing the sql query.
PS I am using postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(ver)
  FROM table
 WHERE name ILIKE '%AB%'
 GROUP BY name, id        -- I assume: id == id' <==> name == name'
```

is it?

Answer (score 0):

select id, name, max(ver) from mytable where name like '%AB%' group by id, name

Answer (score 0):

can you try this sql command.

select id,name,max(ver) from table_name group by id, name having name like '%AB%'